# Get XML content that is not in tags and divide them into array by tags in front of them

Tags: php, xml, parsing

Here's my XML content:

```
<paragraph>
    <textInfo number="1" />Example text one.<textInfo number="2"/>Example text two
</paragraph>
```

I would like to parse it and create array like this:

```
$array = (
    1 => "Example text one",
    2 => "Example text two"
);
```

I tried this:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($file);
var_dump(explode("<textInfo/>", $xml));
```

Result was array with only one key, so in explode function probably doesn't see html tags:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(37) "
    Example text one.Example text two
"
}
```

Also tried this, but it gives me only two empty objects:

```
$paragraphs = $xml->xpath('//textInfo');
```

Can you suggest solution, please?

Comment: Can you show what you have tried so far, XPath can do this.

Comment: @NigelRen I edited my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `explode()` casts the `paragraph` `SimpleXMLElement` into a string. This returns the text content.

```
$xml = <<<'XML'
<paragraph>
    <textInfo number="1" />Example text one.<textInfo number="2"/>Example text two
</paragraph>
XML;
$p = simplexml_load_string($xml);
var_dump($p->getName(), (string)$p);
```

Output:

```
string(9) "paragraph"
string(39) "
    Example text one.Example text two
"
```

You can use `text()` in Xpath expressions to address text nodes. However this does not seem to work with SimpleXML. It returns the parent element node:

```
$p = simplexml_load_string($xml);
$text = $p->xpath('/paragraph/text()')[0];
var_dump($text->getName(), (string)$text);
```

Output:

```
string(9) "paragraph"
string(39) "
    Example text one.Example text two
"
```

So you might need to use DOM. In DOM anything is a node. This allows you to get the separate text nodes:

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadXML($xml);
$xpath = new DOMxpath($document);

foreach ($xpath->evaluate('/paragraph/text()') as $text) {
    var_dump($text->textContent);
}
```

Output:

```
string(5) "
    "
string(17) "Example text one."
string(17) "Example text two
"
```

The first text node in this example is the line break and the indent spaces before the first `<textInfo/>`. Here is a method to recognize that kind of text nodes:

```
$lines = [];
foreach ($xpath->evaluate('/paragraph/text()') as $text) {
    if (!$text->isWhitespaceInElementContent()) {
        $lines[] = $text->textContent;
    }
}
var_dump($lines);
```

Output:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(17) "Example text one."
  [1]=>
  string(17) "Example text two
"
}
```